# docker with virtualbox on windows

Tags: windows, docker, vagrant, virtualbox

**context:**

I have installed vagrant and virtual box. I can't change that setup because it's very delicate and important.

Now when I install docker on windows 10, docker wants to enable hyper-v, but now I can't bring my virtual machine up with vagrant.

**Question:**

Since docker on mac uses the virtual box driver, is there a solution to make docker work with virtual box on windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can install docker directly inside the Linux VM instead of on the windows host. Or you can install the older [docker toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) which is designed to run docker inside of a VirtualBox VM with docker-machine. Note that you'll see added challenges like a difference in how drives are shared for host volumes, and published ports go to the VM IP without the vpnkit forwarding to the host IP/localhost.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't. But can't you just use Docker in your vagrant box?
[For a more detailed description, look here.](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/how-to-use-vagrant-and-docker-for-windows-on-a-hyper-v-system)

Comment: I want to use docker for other purposes and other projects. It just docker affects vagrant

Comment: Nothing can be done I'm afraid. I develop on windows in a folder that is shared through vagrant on a VM and then I run my containers on that Vagrant VM. Testing and debugging can be done through portforwarding etc. Docker is much more stable on Linux anyway.